# How to have a part of substring of a column in a file with shell

Tags: bash, shell, text-extraction

I have a problem,

I have a file named variants.txt with this text inside:

```
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42132048_42132049insT";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42132048_42132049insTT";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42132048_42132049delTT";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131884_42131885insT";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131540_42131541delTC";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131420T>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131222G>A";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131145T>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131125C>G";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131122A>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131119G>A";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131118T>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131112G>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131111T>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131067G>A";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131066G>A";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131063G>A";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131059C>T";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131058C>G";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131023C>G";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131016T>C";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs138100349   ";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs118203758 ";
```

I want to match if the last column (that starts with `name=`) contains substring `g.` and, if so, print everything between `g.` and the trailing `";` to another file.

For example:

```
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42132048_42132049insT";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="NC_000022.11:g.42131125C>G";
```

I want:

```
42132048_42132049insT    
42131125C>G
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
awk '{num=sub(/.*:g\./,"");num+=sub(/\".*/,"");if(num==2){print};num=""}'  Input_file
```

Comment: With GNU Awk you could simplify even further by specifying the entire `name="...` expression as the field separator with `-F`; but this is not portable to mainline Awk.

Comment: @tripleee: Using regexes with `-F` is POSIX-compliant, so it should work fine with any Awk. (You may be thinking of `RS` values, which per POSIX can only be literal, single-char. values.)

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah, you're right, I was confusing the two.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the input field separator regex carefully (via `-F`) allows for a simple solution:

```
awk -F':g\.|";' 'NF>2 {print $2}' file
```

- Regular expression (regex) `:g\.|";` splits each input line into fields by literal `:g.` or (`|`) literal `";`, which splits lines of interest into (at least) *3* fields, with the substring to extract contained in the *2nd* field (`$2`).
- `NF>2` only matches lines with at least 3 fields (`NF` is the number of fields), which ensures that lines that don't contain a substring of interest are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk`, `grep` and `sed`:

```
awk -F'name=' '{print $2}' variants.txt | awk -F'g.' '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/";//g'
```

That is:

1. Take the string from the original file from "name=" to the end.
2. Get only the lines which have the string "g."
3. Take from that "g." to the end
4. Remove the final " and ; characters to get the output as mentioned in your example.

Comment: IMHO: this could be done with single awk/sed, this is a overkill dose of all commands, which may impact the performance of a file processing if it is huge size file.

Comment: @tripleee You're right! I wrongly kept it from another attempts using different commands before choosing `awk`. Edited.

Comment: Still would make more sense as a single Awk script.  The final substitution is easy to do in Awk as well and passing the second field to a second Awk instance just to split the input again is rather hamfisted, given that you could just `split($2, a, /g\./); print a[2]`